# How do you pick out certain values from a list based on their string values in Python?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a list of hyperlinks, with three types of links; `htm`, `csv` and `pdf`. And I would like to just pick out those that are `csv`.

The list contains strings of the form: `csv/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_csv.zip`

I was thinking of running a for loop across the string and just returning values that have first 3 string values are equal to `csv`, but I am not really sure how to do this.

Comment: So you are just looking for `.csv.zip` ? Or also `.csv`?

Comment: post a testable input list and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `link.endswith('csv')` (or `link.endswith('csv.zip')`), where `link` is a string containing that link)

For example:

```
lst = ['csv/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_csv.zip',
       'pdf/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_pdf.zip',
       'html/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_html.zip',
       'csv/damlbmp/20160801damlbmp_zone_csv.zip']

csv_files = [link for link in lst if link.endswith('csv.zip')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is called `links`:

```
[x for x in links if 'csv/' in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
import re
l=["www.h.com","abc.csv","test.pdf","another.csv"] #list of links

def MatchCSV(list):
    matches=[]
    for string in list:
        m=re.findall('[^\.]*\.csv',string)
        if(len(m)>0):
            matches.append(m)
    return matches

print(MatchCSV(l))
[['abc.csv'], ['another.csv']]
```

(endswith is a good option too)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
lst = ['csv/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_csv.zip',
       'pdf/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_pdf.zip',
       'html/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_html.zip',
       'csv/damlbmp/20160801damlbmp_zone_csv.zip']

[i for i in lst if i[:3]=='csv']

# ['csv/damlbmp/20160701damlbmp_zone_csv.zip',
#  'csv/damlbmp/20160801damlbmp_zone_csv.zip']
```

Comment: This is useful thanks, say I wanted to pick all the entries that had 2016 in the filename would I do something like this; [i for i in csv_files if i[12:]=='2016'] ?

Comment: No, you would do something like: `[i for i in csv_files if '2016' in i]`